# How to use WithAnimation with @ObservedObject

Tags: ios, swiftui

Let's say, I have a simple profile screen like that:

```swift
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isSignedIn = false
    
    init() {}
    
    func login() {
        //Some networking here
        isSignedIn = true
    }
    func logout() {
        //Some networking here
        isSignedIn = false
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = Model()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            //ProfileView
            VStack {
                //Some Views with WithAnimation inside
                // ...
 
                Text("Hello, Dear User!")
                Button(action: {
                    self.model.logout()
                }) {
                    Text("Sign Out")
                }
            }
            .opacity(model.isSignedIn ? 1 : 0)

            //LoginView
            VStack {
                Text("Hello, Stranger")
                Button(action: {
                    self.model.login()
                }) {
                    Text("Sign In")
                }
            }
            .opacity(model.isSignedIn ? 0 : 1)
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to apply animation to opacity changing.

The first approach is to use `.animation` modifier. But it has certain drawbacks: it does not work properly if inner view has `WithAnimation` - it overrides animation that was set with `WithAnimation`.

My second approach to use `.onReceive`:

```swift
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isSignedIn = false
    
    init() {}
    
    func login() {
        isSignedIn = true
    }
    func logout() {
        isSignedIn = false
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = Model()
    
    @State var isSignedIn = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            //ProfileView
            VStack {
                Text("Hello, Dear User!")
                Button(action: {
                    self.model.logout()
                }) {
                    Text("Sign Out")
                }
            }
            .opacity(model.isSignedIn ? 1 : 0)

            //LoginView
            VStack {
                Text("Hello, Stranger")
                Button(action: {
                    self.model.login()
                }) {
                    Text("Sign In")
                }
            }
            .opacity(model.isSignedIn ? 0 : 1)
        }
        .onReceive(self.model.$isSignedIn) { value in
            withAnimation(Animation.easeIn) {
                self.isSignedIn = value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are some problems (in my opinion):

- Another `@State` var is required to handle changing in the model
- Each `WithAnimation` block requires separate `.onReceive`

So the question is: is it a correct way to apply `WithAnimation` to `@ObservedObject`, or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the animation directly inside `withAnimation`. This way it will be specific for this change only:

```
Button(action: {
    withAnimation(.easeInOut) { // add animation
        self.model.logout()
    }
}) {
    Text("Sign Out")
}
```

Comment: Looks like it works only when variable is changed directly in logout, if there is complex logic it wont work.

Comment: @Triff Then you may need to stick with `onReceive`.

Answer (score 1):

Your first approach can be changed, so you don't need to use additional @State property

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isSignedIn = false
    
    init() {}
    
    func login() {
        withAnimation(Animation.easeIn) {
        isSignedIn = true
        }
    }
    func logout() {
        withAnimation(Animation.easeIn) {
        isSignedIn = false
        }
    }
}

struct SView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = Model()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            //ProfileView
            VStack {
                Rectangle()
                Text("Hello, Dear User!")
                Button(action: {
                    self.model.logout()
                }) {
                    Text("Sign Out")
                }
            }
            .opacity(model.isSignedIn ? 1 : 0)

            //LoginView
            VStack {
                Rectangle()
                Text("Hello, Stranger")
                Button(action: {
                    self.model.login()
                }) {
                    Text("Sign In")
                }
            }
            .opacity(model.isSignedIn ? 0 : 1)
        }

    }
}
struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SView()
    }
}
```

In your 2nd approach you need to change

```
.opacity(model.isSignedIn ? 1 : 0)
```

to

```
.opacity(self.isSignedIn ? 1 : 0)
```

Comment: Yeah, i thought about that, but decided that model should not control animation, view should do that. But you are rigth, this is another solution.